# if guess_count < guess_limit< wrong with syntax but I can't find out what's wrong about it

Tags: python

```
secret_word = "Lion"


guess = ""


guess = 0



guess_limit= 3



out_of_guesses = False


while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):


    if guess_count < guess_limit


            guess = input("Enter Guess: ")


            guessCount +=1
    else:


        out_of_guesses= True




if out_of_guesses:



    print("Out of guesses, YOU LOSE!")
else:






    print("You win")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a colon at the end of `if guess_count < guess_limit`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm kinda new and I really didn't know what was going on there.